# How to load in TensorFlow C++ a custom op

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, customization, libraries

I've designed a custom op and it works as expected in `python`. I call it with the usual lines of code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
custom_mod = tf.load_op_library('/path/to/.so')

with tf.device("/gpu:0"):
  with tf.Session as sess:
    #(note: function name .exec() depends on kernel code)
    custom_mod_in_graph = custom_mod.exec() 
    sess.run(custom_mod_in_graph)
```

However I need to run the same op with the TF C++ API, unfortunately I can't find any respective calling procedures (i.e.: no equivalent for `tf.load_op_library`).

Are they missing or is there a different way of integrating the ops there?

Comment: Directly linking the Op to the project is no option? Otherwise "dlopen" with  RTLD_GLOBAL might be a good starting point.

Comment: Well I want to ensure that my GPU-kernel continues processing on the GPU for the next TF-Layer. Directly linking sounds like it just encapsulated adds the op to the graph (i.e. my GPU-op returns to the CPU just to call the GPU graph again)